# str_replace , / not working

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I need to find `\` in a string.

**Example**

```
$replacevalue = "%20";
$area = "test\abc.htm";
$valuetoreplace = "\";
$area = str_replace($valuetoreplace,$replacevalue, $area );
```

But it seems like the page goes into a loop or somthing if i do the same with `/`  there are no problem please help

Comment: add slashes to your $valuetoreplace

Comment: The page should have died with a fatal "Parse error".

Answer (score 3):

You need to double your `\`s as it is an escape character for strings... So:

```
% php
<?php
$area = str_replace("\\","",'test\abc.htm');
echo $area."\n";
?>
```

Yields... `testabc.htm`

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$replacevalue           =   "%20";
$area               =   "test\abc.htm";

$valuetoreplace     =   "\\";
$area               =   str_replace($valuetoreplace,$replacevalue, $area );
```

or another solution is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482637/replacing-backslash-with-another-symbol-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

valuetoreplace should be "\\".

Answer (score 1):

Well "\" this character is an escape character so compiler refers to it as an escape not as a "\", just add another one so it will escape itself "\" and your code will work

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
$valuetoreplace     =   "\";
```

to

```
$valuetoreplace     =   "\\";
```

Read more about [escaping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) characters.

Answer (score 0):

'\' is a special character add a double `\\` to escape it